# Banner AdMob in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to put a banner AdMob in my recyclerview like every 5 items there should be banner AdMob
I scan the internet a lot but people who is done use .ViewHolder because of that i cannot find any example of putting banner AdMob in RecyclerView with .PostHolder
And i use .PostHolder not .ViewHolder

How I can do that?

Thanks

this is my adapter class:

```
public class MainActivityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivityAdapter.PostHolder>{
private ArrayList<String> fiyatList;
private ArrayList<String> açıklamaList;
private ArrayList<String > isimList;





private String [] colors = {"#d2d2d1","#404040"};


public MainActivityAdapter(ArrayList<String> fiyatList,ArrayList<String> açıklamaList,ArrayList<String> isimList){
    this.fiyatList=fiyatList;
    this.açıklamaList=açıklamaList;
    this.isimList=isimList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MainActivityAdapter.PostHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_adapter,parent,false);


    return new PostHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainActivityAdapter.PostHolder holder, int position) {



    holder.fiyat.setText("₺"+" "+fiyatList.get(position));
    holder.açıklama.setText(açıklamaList.get(position));
    holder.isim.setText(isimList.get(position));




    if (position%2==0) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[0]));
    }
    else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[1]));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fiyatList.size();
}

public class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView açıklama,fiyat,isim;

    public PostHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        açıklama=itemView.findViewById(R.id.açıklama);
        fiyat=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fiyat);
        isim=itemView.findViewById(R.id.isim);





    }
}



}
```

And my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RequestQueue mQueue;
Button buttonr,buttonl,döviz,zirai;
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
ArrayList<String> isimList;
ArrayList<String> fiyatList;
ArrayList<String> açıklamaList;
MainActivityAdapter mainActivityAdapter;
ArrayList<String > dövizler;
ArrayList<String > semboller;
ArrayList<String > açıklama;
AdView AdView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonl=findViewById(R.id.buttonl);
    buttonr=findViewById(R.id.buttonr);
    zirai=findViewById(R.id.zirai);
    döviz=findViewById(R.id.döviz);

    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this);


    buttonl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    zirai.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    döviz.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    açıklamaList=new ArrayList<>();
    fiyatList=new ArrayList<>();
    isimList=new ArrayList<>();

    semboller=new ArrayList<>();
    açıklama=new ArrayList<>();
    dövizler=new ArrayList<>();


  //  dövizler.add(0,"1");
  //  açıklama.add(0,"TL");
  //  semboller.add(0,"TL");

    zirai.setEnabled(false);



    jsonParse();

    getDataFromFireBase();

    RecyclerView recyclerView1=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mainActivityAdapter=new MainActivityAdapter(fiyatList,açıklamaList,isimList);
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);






}
public void BUTTONR(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);

    intent.putExtra("DÖVİZLER",açıklama);
    intent.putExtra("DÖVİZLERFİYAT",dövizler);
    intent.putExtra("ziraiisimList",isimList);
    intent.putExtra("ziraifiyat",fiyatList);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void ZİRAİ(View view){

    döviz.setEnabled(true);
    zirai.setEnabled(false);


    RecyclerView recyclerView1=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mainActivityAdapter=new MainActivityAdapter(fiyatList,açıklamaList,isimList);
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);

}
public void DÖVİZ(View view){

    döviz.setEnabled(false);
    zirai.setEnabled(true);


    RecyclerView recyclerView1=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mainActivityAdapter=new MainActivityAdapter(dövizler,açıklama,semboller);
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);

}

public void onBackPressed() {
    closeContextMenu();

}
public void  getDataFromFireBase(){
    CollectionReference collectionReference=(CollectionReference) firebaseFirestore.collection("Ürünler");
    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e!=null){

            }
            if (queryDocumentSnapshots!=null){

                fiyatList.clear();
                isimList.clear();
                açıklamaList.clear();
                int count=0;
                for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot:queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()){
                    Map<String,Object> data = snapshot.getData();

                    //Casting
                    String açıklama= (String) data.get("Açıklama");
                    String fiyat= (String) data.get("Fiyat");
                    String isim= (String) data.get("İsim");

                    açıklamaList.add(açıklama);
                    fiyatList.add(fiyat);
                    isimList.add(isim);

                    mainActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();





                }
            }


        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant put a banner ad inside recycler view but I think I know what you want for that we should use Native Advanced Ads to load an ad in recycler view Check this documentation for more information and there are lots of tutorials too

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced